# Javascript: Quickly lookup value in object (like we can with properties)

Tags: javascript, object, loops, lookup

I have an object that has pairs of replacement values used for simple encoding / decoding (not for security, just for a convenience; too complicated to explain it all here). It's in the form

```
var obj = {x: y,
           x: y,
           ...
          };
```

where 'x' is the value when encoded and 'y' is the decoded value.

Decoding is simple: I loop through the characters of the string, and look up the `charAt(i)` value in the object via brackets: `obj[ str.charAt(i) ]`. (I'm leaving out the check to see whether we need an uppercase or lowercase version (all key/values in the object are lowercase), but that's simple enough.)

To encode, I of course have to look for the value in the object, rather than the property. Currently, I'm looping through the properties with a `for ... in ...` loop and checking the values against the `charAt(i)` value. My current code is:

```
var i, j,
    output = '',
    str = 'Hello World!',
    obj = {'s':'d',
           'm':'e',
           'e':'h',
           'x':'l',
           'z':'o',
           'i':'r',
           'a':'w',
           'o':'!',
           '-':' '};
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (j in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, j) &&
            Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(obj, j)) {
            if (obj[j] === str.charAt(i)) {
                output += j;
                break;
            } else if (obj[j].toUpperCase() === str.charAt(i)) {
                output += j.toUpperCase();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
alert(output);
```

I innately feel like there should be a more efficient way of doing this. (Of course having a reversed object, {y: x}, is an option. But not a good one.) Is this the best way, or is there a better? In essence, I'd love to be able to do `var prop = obj[value]` just like I can do `var value = obj[prop]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's more efficient to loop just once beforehand to create a reverse map:

```
var str = "Hello World!",
    output = '',
    map = {
      "s":"d", "m":"e",
      "e":"h", "x":"l",
      "z":"o", "i":"r",
      "a":"w", "o":"!",
      "-":" "
    },
    reverseMap = {}

for (j in map){
  if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(map, j)) continue
  reverseMap[map[j]] = j
}

output = str.replace(/./g, function(c){
  return reverseMap[c] || reverseMap[c.toLowerCase()].toUpperCase()
})

console.log(output)
```

Instead of doing `str.length * map.length`, you'll do `map.length + str.length` operations.

Comment: Yes! I'd upvote you twice if I could, since this combines both of the suggested improvements into one. This is definitely my accepted answer (barring any other amazing version...). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a reversed version of the mapping programmatically (instead of by hand) and use it instead.

```
var rev = {}
for (key in obj)
    rev[obj[key]] = key
```

Comment: You know what? You're a genius... ;) This is one of those "DUH" moments for me. Mapping by hand definitely was not an option, especially if I want to be able to extend the scope of the original. (I've seen code that has two versions of fairly long key/value pairs, and I cringe at the thought of how much time was spent typing them up, and editing as the code developed.)

Answer (score 3):

A reverse encoder would make more sense, but you can write a replace function without all the hasOwnProperty etc.tests.

```
var str= 'Hello World!',
obj={
    's':'d',
    'm':'e',
    'e':'h',
    'x':'l',
    'z':'o',
    'i':'r',
    'a':'w',
    'o':'!',
    '-':' '
}
str= str.replace(/./g, function(w){
    for(var p in obj){
        if(obj[p]=== w) return p;
        if(obj[p]=== w.toLowerCase()) return p.toUpperCase();
    };
    return w;
});
```

**returned value: (String) Emxxz-Azixso**

Comment: I had no idea you could pass a function to replace like that! I'm assuming then that the current to_replace value (/./) is passed to the function, hence the w? Much more elegant and readable version, I'll definitely think about this.

Comment: @kennebec you still need the `hasOwnProperty` check to avoid extraneous data from prototype extensions. The declared values will override them, but it could return a match instead of raising an error when there was none.

Comment: @kennebec: I agree with Ricardo on that. Even though this is all code I'm writing myself, always better to be safe than sorry. And I like getting myself in good habits. I think `hasOwnProperty` should be sufficient. The reason I had `propertyIsEnumerable` is due to [this info from Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html#p51c5b387).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for array keys check here.

https://raw.github.com/kvz/phpjs/master/functions/array/array_keys.js

```
function array_keys (input, search_value, argStrict) {
    var search = typeof search_value !== 'undefined', tmp_arr = [], strict = !!argStrict, include = true, key = '';

    if (input && typeof input === 'object' && input.change_key_case) {
        return input.keys(search_value, argStrict);
    }

    for (key in input) {
        if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            include = true;
            if (search) {
                if (strict && input[key] !== search_value) include = false;
                else if (input[key] != search_value) include = false;
            }
            if (include) tmp_arr[tmp_arr.length] = key;
        }
    }

    return tmp_arr;
}
```