# JavaScript: Repeated code vs. extra functions when code length is same

Tags: javascript, conventions, code-organization, simplify

After updating my code based on answers to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974493/javascript-quickly-lookup-value-in-object-like-we-can-with-properties/10974721), I came up with the following solution:

```
var Coder = (function() {
    var controlWords = [
            ['ONE','OO'],
            ['TWO','TT'],
            ['THREE','RR'],
          //['...','..'],
            ['END','NN']
        ],
        map = {
            '0':' ', '1':'_', '2':',',
            '3':'.', '4':'?', '5':'!',
            '6':'\'','7':'"', '8':'(',
            '9':')', 'a':'o', 'b':'d',
            'c':'a', 'd':'e', 'e':'p',
            'f':'i', 'g':'f', 'h':'v',
            'i':'u', 'j':'l', 'k':'m',
            'l':'y', 'm':'q', 'n':'x',
            'o':'b', 'p':'j', 'q':'t',
            'r':'n', 's':'z', 't':'w',
            'u':'k', 'v':'h', 'w':'s',
            'x':'c', 'y':'r', 'z':'g'
        },
        reverseMap = (function() {
            var j, tmp = {};
            for (j in map){
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(map, j))
                    tmp[map[j]] = j;
            }
            return tmp;
        })(),
        value, i,
        encode = function(data) {
            var input = (typeof data == 'string' ? data : '');
console.log('Input to encode: '+input);
            for (i = 0; i < controlWords.length; i++) {
                value = new RegExp(controlWords[i][0],'g');
                input = input.replace(value,controlWords[i][1]);
            }
console.log('Encode step 1: '+input);
            input = input.replace(/./g, function(c){
                return reverseMap[c]
                    || reverseMap[c.toLowerCase()].toUpperCase();
            });
console.log('Encoding output: '+input);
            return {length: input.length, data: input};
        },
        decode = function(data) {
            var input = (typeof data == 'string' ? data : '');
console.log('Input to decode: '+input);
            input = input.replace(/./g, function(c){
                return map[c]
                    || map[c.toLowerCase()].toUpperCase();
            });
console.log('Decode step 1: '+input);
            for (i = 0; i < controlWords.length; i++) {
                value = new RegExp(controlWords[i][1],'g');
                input = input.replace(value,controlWords[i][0]);
            }
console.log('Decoding output: '+input);
            return {length: input.length, data: input};
        };
    return {encode: encode, decode: decode};
})();
var str = 'ONE Hello, TWO JavaScript THREE World! END',
    enc = Coder.encode(str).data,
    dec = Coder.decode(enc).data;
```

As you can see, there's a lot of fully- or nearly-repeated code. The only meaningful differences are the order in which the two transformations happen, whether `map` or `reverseMap` is used, and which index of each control word array is used as the regex and which as the replacement value.

To abide by the concept of wrapping repeated code in a sub-function and calling that function, I made the following attempt. It defines the two transformations as internal functions, and then based on the value of the `type` argument, decides the rest.

```
var Coder = (function() {
    var controlWords = [ /* same */ ],
        map = { /* same */ },
        reverseMap = /* same */,
        code = function(data, type) {
            var input = (typeof data == 'string' ? data : ''),
                mapping, x, y, value, i,
                transform = function() {
                    return input.replace(/./g, function(c){
                        return mapping[c]
                            || mapping[c.toLowerCase()].toUpperCase();
                    });
                },
                replace = function() {
                    for (i = 0; i < controlWords.length; i++) {
                        value = new RegExp(controlWords[i][x],'g');
                        input = input.replace(value,controlWords[i][y]);
                    }
                    return input;
                };
            if (type == 'decode') {
                mapping = map;
                x = 1;
                y = 0;
                input = transform();
                input = replace();
            } else if (type == 'encode') {
                mapping = reverseMap;
                x = 0;
                y = 1;
                input = replace();
                input = transform();
            } else {
                throw new Error('Invalid type argument!');
            }
            return {data: input, length: input.length};
        };
    return {code: code};
})();
var str = 'ONE Hello, TWO JavaScript THREE World! END',
    enc = Coder.code(str, 'encode').data,
    dec = Coder.code(enc, 'decode').data;
```

However, you might notice that this code is actually longer. It's still more easily extended, if I wanted to add more types than 'encode' and 'decode' (not going to). But currently less efficient?

I then went back to the version with two functions (to avoid the passing of and check of 'type'):

```
var Coder = (function() {
    var controlWords = [ /* same */ ],
        map = { /* same */ },
        reverseMap = { /* same */ },
        input, mapping, x, y, value, i,
        transform = function() {
            return input.replace(/./g, function(c){
                return mapping[c]
                    || mapping[c.toLowerCase()].toUpperCase();
            });
        },
        replace = function() {
            for (i = 0; i < controlWords.length; i++) {
                value = new RegExp(controlWords[i][x],'g');
                input = input.replace(value,controlWords[i][y]);
            }
            return input;
        },
        encode = function(data) {
            input = (typeof data == 'string' ? data : '');
            mapping = reverseMap;
            x = 0;
            y = 1;
            input = replace();
            input = transform();
            return {length: input.length, data: input};
        },
        decode = function(data) {
            input = (typeof data == 'string' ? data : '');
            mapping = map;
            x = 1;
            y = 0;
            input = transform();
            input = replace();
            return {length: input.length, data: input};
        };
    return {encode: encode, decode: decode};
})();
// Call methods same as first example
```

So lengthy post to basically ask, which is better, repeated code or extra functions/checks, when it doesn't really help code length and there's no plans to extend the code or release it as a public project? Which of these is the most elegant solution, or is there an even better?

**EDIT**

One way I thought of to clean it up in general is to remove the variable declarations of `mapping`, `x`, and `y` and just pass them as arguments to `replace` and `transform`. This would yield

```
decode = function(data) {
    var input = (typeof data == 'string' ? data : '');
    input = transform(map);
    input = replace(1,0);
    return {length: input.length, data: input};
}
```

Comment: If you have no plans of extending the code or letting anyone read it, why do you even care about its appearance? I like the way the last code chunk looks, personally, but if the situation is like you say it is, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Two reasons: 1) Always develop good habits, never bad ones. 2) Readability is important, even in one's own projects. I know that I at least have returned to old projects to be a bit confused by what I was doing, even with comments. (oK, three reasons.) 3) It's possible one of those is slightly better performance-wise.

Comment: @RobG: I'm not sure what made you think I'm expecting a certain order. Hmm. I'm not actually - I've seen the issue you mention brought up in quite a few forums. When I define 'reverseMap' based on 'map', it doesn't matter the order, just that the paired keys/values will remain consistent. Which they will. And then in the transform function, I'm simply looking up a value via a key, which doesn't care about order.

Comment: And the problem with arrays is that I CAN'T look up a key easily. The only way to get the key/value pair setup like an object is to do nested arrays like in 'controlWords', or to rely on an "every other" approach in a normal array [x1, y1, x2, y2, ..., xn, yn]. Then you could look up the "value" of a "key" with arr[arr.indexOf(key)+1]. Ugly compared to obj[key]. A similar issue with arrays is that reverse wouldn't work with nested arrays either. It could work with the second version, but back to the ugly issue.