# JavaScript - What is the better way to skip an input when necessary for a code editor?

Tags: javascript, editor

I am programming a web app like an online code editor. One of the basic functions is that when users input, say, a left parenthesis symbol **"("**, the editor will automatically add the right one **")"** for you.

So an immediate idea is that I create an object for that, defined as follows:

```
var pairCharData = {
    "{": "}",
    "(": ")",
    "\"":"\"",
    "'":"'"
};
```

That's not the end. I want the editor to be smarter so it should skip the input when necessary. For example, when I input in the editor a right parenthesis symbol immediately after I just added a left one (at that time, the right parenthesis already existed!), the editor is expected to only move the cursor but without showing one more duplicated one.

So I want to check if a next user-input character is one expected.
I created another map as follows:

```
var pairCharDataReverse = {
    "}": "{",
    ")": "(",
    "\"":"\"",
    "'":"'"
};
```

This is, you know, just the reverse version of the first map. My idea is to keep track of the input key from users. Here is my implementation

```
if(key in pairCharDataReverse) {
var leftPair = pairCharDataReverse[key];
if(this.lastKey === leftPair) {
    this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start +1;
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

As I add more pairs of characters, I have to modify both maps, which is not I want.
I guess there must be another better way to store the data with less pain. Maybe with another data structure or there is just a trick that I really wonder.

Comment: Do you just want to be able to do a reverse lookup on your first map? Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974493/javascript-quickly-lookup-value-in-object-like-we-can-with-properties)?

Comment: @LarryTurtis It worked. Thank you, although I wondered if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<select>` element with `<option>` elements corresponding the characters the user selects to wrap text within. User selects text, user selects `<option>`, `javascript` performs action which wraps selected text in selected `<option>` `.value`.

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
var select = document.querySelector("select");
var text;
select.onchange = function(e) {
  if (text) {
    var option = this.value.split("");
    textarea.value = textarea.value.slice(0, text[0]) 
                     + option[0] 
                     + textarea.value.slice(text[0], text[1])
                     + option[1]
                     + textarea.value.slice(text[1]);
  }
  this.value = text = null;
}
textarea.onselect = function(e) {
  text = [this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd]
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option value="()">()</option>
  <option value="[]">[]</option>
  </select><br>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Instead of attempting to programmatically insert characters as user types, allow user to select the characters they choose to wrap selected text within.

Comment: I didn't get your point. Can you add more details and why I need a selection elem?